# Make jquery lazyload plugin work inside the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

The lazyload jquery plugin delays loading of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport (visible part of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them.

The problem is I have a thumbnail gallery with about 40 small images, 10 per line.
If I load the site, I can see 3 rows of images (30 images in total). The plugin does wonders with the other 10, but I still get 30 HTTP requests at once.

Can this plugin be modified to delay images in the viewport? maybe in groups?
Display the first 10, wait half a second, display the next 10, wait again and so on.

P.S. Lazyload has an option to delay loading all images until the DOM is ready, but if scripts like jquery or others load a bit slowish sometimes - I will see a site with no images.

Here is a link to the plugin [source code](https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js).

Comment: Can you add your implementation code also, js and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually add a class to each image in the row of 10 and a separate class to the images in the row after and so on, you can trigger a load of each row like so:

```
$(function() {          
    $("img").lazyload({
        event : "timedload"
    });
});

$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { $("img.row1").trigger("timedload")}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { $("img.row2").trigger("timedload")}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() { $("img.row3").trigger("timedload")}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { $("img.row3").trigger("timedload")}, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Lazyloading is not about 'delayed' display. You really don't want to send requests untill you need the image/javascript/css.

Comment: I agree. 'webmasters' wanted to delay the functionality though due to the 30 images that exist in the view-port upon page load.

Comment: I adjusted the code to trigger the load event, vs visually delaying the loading of the images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only worried about the request amount you can use [Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) to bundle your images.

For example you can bundle the first row in one sprite, the second in another and so on. This reduces your 40 requests to 4!

Of course this requires that

- images are either static, so each user sees the same images or
- some kind of server sided "Image Sprites" generator. However neither
  Google nor Facebook are using a server sided "Image Sprites"
  generator to bundle their images